# Polymorphic method call not compiling

Tags: c#, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have the following polymorphic method call with two abstract Segment parameters, however i have an error associated with this call

```
    public static void Connected(Segment s1, Segment s2)
        {
            s1.Connected(s2);
            //further working code
        }
```

I have defined a number of abstract methods

```
    public abstract bool Connected(derivedSegment0 s);
    public abstract bool Connected(derivedSegment1 s);
    public abstract bool Connected(derivedSegment2 s);
    public abstract bool Connected(derivedSegment3 s);
```

Which for each derived class have implemented each of these (so 16 in total in this example)

```
    public override bool Connected(derivedSegment0 s)
    {
        //working code
    }
```

Its unclear to me why the call doesn't compile. I have the error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Segment.Connected(derivedSegment1)' has some invalid arguments. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to do [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), which C# does not support.
In C#, all overload resolution (except `dynamic`) is done entirely at compile-time.

Instead, you can use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).